# fixture 'pylon_config_missing_usageplan' not found while running pytest-bdd

Tags: pytest, pytest-bdd

```
    @scenario('../features/config.feature', 'Loading a valid config')
def test_config():
    pass

@given("I have provided a valid pylon config",target_fixture="pylon_config")
def pylon_config():
    input_data = {
            
        }
    return input_data

@when("The configuration is loaded")
def excute_pylon_config(pylon_config):
    createFilterPattern(pylon_config)


@then("It should be enriched with the expected FilterPatterns")
def no_error_message(pylon_config):
    test_data1= {
            
            }
        
    test_data_2 = {
       
    }
    result = pylon_config
    

@scenario('../features/config.feature', 'Missing usagePlan section')
def test_missing_usageplan():
    pass

@given("I have provided a pylon config with a missing key",target_fixture="pylon_config_missing_usageplan")
def pylon_config_missing_usageplan():
    input_data = {
            'metricFilters': {
                'defaults': {
                    'xyz': []
                }
            }
        }
    return input_data

@when("The configuration is loaded")
def excute_pylon_config_missing_usageplan(pylon_config_missing_usageplan):
    try: 
        createFilterPattern(pylon_config_missing_usageplan)
    except KeyError:
        pass

@then("I should receive an exception")
def error_message_pylon_config_missing_usageplan(pylon_config_missing_usageplan):
    print(pylon_config_missing_usageplan)
```

I have written multiple test case with specifying target_fixture in both @given scenario.

While running the test case it's throwing an error with

**fixture 'pylon_config_missing_usageplan' not found**

available fixtures: cache, capfd, capfdbinary, caplog, capsys, capsysbinary, doctest_namespace, monkeypatch, pylon_config, pytestbdd_given_I have provided a pylon config with a missing key, pytestbdd_given_I have provided a valid pylon config, pytestbdd_given_trace, pytestbdd_then_I should receive an exception, pytestbdd_then_It should be enriched with the expected FilterPatterns, pytestbdd_then_trace, pytestbdd_when_The configuration is loaded, pytestbdd_when_trace, pytestconfig, record_property, record_testsuite_property, record_xml_attribute, recwarn, tmp_path, tmp_path_factory, tmpdir, tmpdir_factory
use 'pytest --fixtures [testpath]' for help on them.

Can anyone help me over here?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is, that the step `When The configuration is loaded` has two different implementations in code:

```py
@when("The configuration is loaded")
def excute_pylon_config(pylon_config):
    createFilterPattern(pylon_config)

@when("The configuration is loaded")
def excute_pylon_config_missing_usageplan(pylon_config_missing_usageplan):
    try: 
        createFilterPattern(pylon_config_missing_usageplan)
    except KeyError:
        pass
```

The function `excute_pylon_config_missing_usageplan` overrides the step implementation of `excute_pylon_config` and therefore if you try to load the pylon config in scenario `Loading a valid config`, pytest-bdd actually tries to execute the function `excute_pylon_config_missing_usageplan`, which is expecting the fixture `pylon_config_missing_usageplan` (which is not available in this scenario ...)

## Solutions

1. Have two distinct steps for loading a valid/invalid config, e.g. `When The configuration is loaded` and `When The invalid configuration is loaded` (I would recommend this approach, since it is simpler and easier to read than solution 2)
2. Add a variable to the step for loading the configuration which contains the type of the configuration

## Example of variable in configuration loading step:

```py
@when(parsers.parse("The {config_type} configuration is loaded"))
def excute_pylon_config(request, config_type):
    if config_type == 'valid':
        # Retrieve fixture dynamically by name
        pylon_config = request.getfixturevalue('pylon_config')
        createFilterPattern(pylon_config)
    else:
        # Retrieve fixture dynamically by name
        pylon_config_missing_usageplan = request.getfixturevalue('pylon_config_missing_usageplan')
        try: 
            createFilterPattern(pylon_config_missing_usageplan)
        except KeyError:
            pass
```